# Spring SSO and account creation

Tags: spring, oauth, single-sign-on

So I'm working on a university project in which my group needs to create an android application that talks to a backend build with spring. So far we've been using JWT's for user authentication/authorization and everything was fine and dandy. However, our client wants to have single sign-on with Google and Facebook and of course to still be able to create an account, just like this form (but on android, not a browser).

I have spent the last month researching and googling how to do this and especially how it's supposed to integrate with the android app. I feel like I'm missing a key point because I see this everywhere, so I assume that is not that hard to do. As much as I understand, I can have two endpoints: login/google, login/facebook to get authorised with their authorisation server. That I have, I followed this guide and I understand 70-ish% of it.

Then my idea is to have users that are logging in for the first time to be saved in our database. I'm not entirely sure how to do that (because I'm not entire sure how the SSO spring code works..). My main questions tho are:

- How to have both social login with google/fb and the ability to make an account/login with credentials.
- If the user was to make an account, do I have my own authorisation server where I store credentials or do I manage that on the main server.
- How do I handle that from the android app? Do I store the refresh token or do I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things

1. You want to integrate with spring-social for any social providers such as google/fb. Add the dependency and configure by following the tutorials
   See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/wiki/quick-start
2. If you also want users to create their own account, u do not need an authorization server. What u need is spring security vanilla form setup with a configuration

Something like

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
}
```

3. Yes but i recommend u find an oauth library you can just plug in.. and hopefully it will handle the refresh_token logic for you.. you should not need to implement these things yourself.

I hope this helped some, these questions you asked are very broad.. but hopefully it will get you somewhere.